Convert FMU to non-direct feedthrough in order to perform Simulink Co-Simulation in parallel
I am currently using some Co-simulation FMUs generated by Dymola inside Simulink.
I would like to speed up the simulation by using the Multithreaded Simulation as specified here
It is said "You can also run a model on multiple threads if the model has a nondirect feedthrough block followed by a direct feedthrough block"
For that purpose I am trying to convert the FMU generated by Dymola from direct feedthrough (DF) to non-direct feedthrough (NDF).
I guess that the FMU is DF because of this message during the FMU generation :

The inputs of my models are classical inputs from the MSL.
A way I found in literature is to add a delay block after the inputs in order to obtain a NDF FMU.

Does anyone know a better solution to generate a NDF FMU?
Is it possible to define the unit delay inside Dymola to be a unit delay from the actual step size of the solver and not from a given delay time? This could help for simulation performances.

For question 2 : The delay block does not seem to fit. Perhaps create a block with the pre() operator? A related question was asked here but for a different need and without any developpement from decades and I dont know if the answer here is still true

Perhaps you can try removing the direct feedthrough dependencies declared in the model description of the FMU? Sometimes this works and the importer will simply conclude there is no feedthrough and interact with the FMU as such. Let me know if you need more details.

Do you mean to delete all the dependencies under each "Unknown index=number" inside the  part of the xml file?

Yes @PYF . It's a bit of a hack, and will introduce delays, but allows you to at least interact with those FMUs. If your simulation is sensitive to the delays, then you will be in trouble.
